# Is there a way to only show my self-made plugin when a specific Wordpress users logs in?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to hide content from a specific WP users? For instance a users logs in with a non admin role. He will only be allowed to see the plugin page.

Comment: There are a lot of possible ways to do that, what is the best way depends on your specific needs. I suggest you read this and the links at the end: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: You could use the above comment in combination with with `current_user_can()`. Read more about that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Custom role :

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'cloneRole');

function cloneRole()
{
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $adm = $wp_roles->get_role('administrator');
    //Adding a 'new_role' with all admin caps
    $wp_roles->add_role('new_role', 'My Custom Role', $adm->capabilities);
}
?>
```

User(My Custom Role) can see only plugin menu while login :

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){
  if( get_user_role() == 'My Custom Role')
  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
  remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack* 
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
  remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
 // remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
  remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>

function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    return $user_role;
}
```

**You can go for any plugin**

You need to use the right hooks (which are not always the same as the URLs/slugs), and it doesn't hurt to use a hook that runs later (e.g., admin_init):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_136058_remove_menu_pages' );

function wpse_136058_remove_menu_pages() {

    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf' );
    remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' );
}
```

You can use the following to debug:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_136058_debug_admin_menu' );

function wpse_136058_debug_admin_menu() {

    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $GLOBALS[ 'menu' ], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```

This gives (for my setup) the following for the Contact Form 7 plugin menu page:

```
[27] => Array
        (
            [0] => Formular
            [1] => wpcf7_read_contact_forms
            [2] => wpcf7
            [3] => Contact Form 7
            [4] => menu-top menu-icon-generic toplevel_page_wpcf7 menu-top-last
            [5] => toplevel_page_wpcf7
            [6] => none
        )
```

The array element with key 2 is what you are looking for: wpcf7.

Comment: I want to hide a specific plugin.

Comment: can you give me plugin name

Comment: upload image of your admin plugin list

Comment: I can help you if you need